# use subset() in R with changing subset column names

Tags: r, subset

I have some data with column names. I need to subset the column DF.classifications_0.25_0.02_268. However, DF.classifications is a base with the numbers always changing. I have tried grep, names, colnames in the subset() and still getting errors. Any solutions? I really want this to be used in the subset() for various reason.

An example of failed code:

```
cts.seurat.obj.filtered <- subset(cts.seurat.obj.filtered, colnames(cts.seurat.obj.filtered@meta.data)[6] == "Singlet")


names(cts.seurat.obj@meta.data)
[1] "orig.ident"                       "nCount_RNA"
[3] "nFeature_RNA"                     "percent.mt"
[5] "pANN_0.25_0.02_268"               "DF.classifications_0.25_0.02_268"
```

Comment: The `subset` in `subset` is used for row filtering.  If you need to select the column names, use `select` i.e. `subset(cts.seurat.obj.filtered, select = colnames(cts.seurat.obj.filtered@meta.data)[6])`

Comment: how would you filter by == singlet this way?

Comment: Are you trying to select column only if the `[6]` is "Singlet" or else what do you want to get  Perhaps, you can do `if( colnames(cts.seurat.obj.filtered@meta.data)[6] == "Singlet") subset(ts.seurat.obj.filtered, select = "Singlet")`

Comment: I am trying to filter my data by column 6 and return a new filtered data that only has singlet in column 6. However, each new data set will have a different DF.classifications assignment.

Comment: `filter` is for filtering rows, select is for selecting columns

Comment: got it, your if statment worked. Wasnt even coming from that direction.

Comment: Why not use `subset(cts.seurat.obj.filtered, cts.seurat.obj.filtered[[colnames(cts.seurat.obj.filtered@meta.data)[6]]] == "Singlet")` if it is for subsetting the rows

Comment: right up below and will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `select` the column only if the 6th column name is 'Singlet'

```
if( colnames(cts.seurat.obj.filtered@meta.data)[6] == "Singlet")    
 {
   subset(cts.seurat.obj.filtered, select = Singlet)
}
```